# Xamarin XAML Multi language in StringFormat

Tags: xaml, xamarin, string-formatting

I have a simple (Android) application in Xamarin. 
Until now, it uses a single language, now I add a translation for a second language. I use resource .resx files and I use it in XAML like this:

```
<Span Text="{x:Static resource:AppResources.Text1}" />
```

where Text1 is loaded from a resource file (depend on language). 
I don't know how to do a similar thing in the next line, where I use Binding and StringFormat:

```
<Label Text="{Binding Datum, StringFormat='Some text: {0}'}" />
```

I tried with:

```
<Label Text="{Binding Datum, StringFormat='{x:Static resource:AppResources.Text2} {0}'}" />
```

but it didn't work.

Any idea?

Comment: you use localized resources to translate static text.  If you have dynamic text, that approach doesn't work.  What type of data is "Datum"?

Comment: Datum (=Date in English) is string.

Comment: If dynamic text can't be used in that way, what do you suggest? Is there any possible IF (depends on a device language) in XAML?

Comment: if it's a DateTime, then .NET will localize and format it for you according to the device's locale settings

Comment: if you need some localized text in the label next to the DateTime, you can break it up into spans and use a localized resource for just the text

Comment: It could be a good idea. I'm a noob but will try it. Otherwise, I will ask for help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use Spans to combine data and text

```
<Label>
  <Label.FormattedText>
    <FormattedString>
      <Span Text="{x:Static resource:AppResources.Text1}" />
      <Span Text="{Binding Datum}" />
    </FormattedString>
  </Label.FormattedText>
</Label>
```